# Are 3rd Party Mac Chargers ok for using as spare parts to repair an original charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, charger, 3rd-party

My original Macbook Air charger (5 years old) still works great, but the cord after the power block is torn up and all the sheathing is almost off. The bottom point (including the brick) work great and have no issues.

I was wondering if I could order a 3rd party charger and change out the top section of that? Is it safe?

Most of the questions similar to this are moreso about the entire charger, and the answers say how unreliable and unsafe the power module is. Since this isn't being replaced, do the same problems exist?

I do have to find a charger that supports this changeability though.

(This might get marked as duplicate, but I haven't found an answer and this question is slightly different)

Comment: "Before" and "after" the brick is a bit vague.  Do you mean the MagSafe end or the end that plugs into the mains?   As for 3rd party chargers, I'm just going leave these two videos here: [video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8nLuNJvvMY) and [video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ot9qy61e6-g)

Comment: The end that plugs into the power is fine. This includes the power converter. The end that connects to the computer (the magsafe part) is tattered and needs a new one.

Comment: Buy a new adapter.  I have the skills to crack it open and solder a replacement cable and I can tell you from first hand experience, it's a royal PITA.  A non-OEM replacement adapter is, quite simply, too much of a risk when plugging into your MacBook.  If you send 18V down the wrong pin, it's goodbye MB.

Comment: I wasnt going to solder it... You can slide off the top MagSafe cable.

Comment: How can you be sure that the wiring of the new cable (on the charger side of things) is the same as in the original?

Comment: fair point, but I don't see why that would be different. Especially if they use the same connector as on the original.

Comment: I'd say - if you have to ask, then you don't have the technical knowledge to do this & should, for safety reasons, leave it alone.

Comment: To swap out the magsafe portion of a 3rd party charger? lol

Comment: I don't see why you'd buy a 3rd party charger only to destroy it for the cable when the [cable is available by itself](https://ebay.to/2LKdcWn).  What I have done in the past to ensure genuine parts is buy a [broken charger](https://ebay.to/2AgM5RM) and cut the cable off and splice it to the working charger. If you have to open the charger housing, my advice is don't.  It's glued together and at best you'll have to duct tape everything back together because nothing will snap back into place.